# Conditional Variance For Discrete & Continous Random Variable X

Tags: statistics, variance

> Hi guys, can help me to understand the notation we used to represent **V** "Explaining the formulas, Visualization, ...", I got the idea of Expectation Value **E** but, I did not get Conditional Variance. Thanks! [image: Conditional Variance]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you familiar with the definition of variance?
$$V(X) := E[(X-E[X])^2] = E[X^2] - E[X]^2.$$
It is the expected square distance of $X$ from its mean. The last expression $E[X^2] - E[X]^2$ is a common way to compute the variance.

Conditional variance extends this notion with conditioning on some event or random variable. Essentially, it is the same as variance, but conditioned on $A$. Note that the formula simply takes $E[X^2] - E[X]^2$ but replaces each expectation with the conditional expectation to get $E[X^2 \mid A] - E[X \mid A]^2$.

$$V(X \mid A) := E[(X-E[X])^2 \mid A] = E[X^2 \mid A] - E[X \mid A]^2.$$

Comment: Actually, I am not. Please, can you give me a link where it's explained well? Thanks.

Comment: @White159 Surely the source you are reading (from which you got your picture) explains it?

Comment: Unfortunately not, we have got very bad notes ..... I would appreciate it if you provide a link ...

Comment: @White159 http://www.randomservices.org/random/expect/Variance.html